# HTML website Javascript alert after php form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have Html website. There is newsletter signup form in the html. It is processed by php script file for sending the email.  After the form submission I want it back to the original page and also an alert message for "Thank you for newsletter signup"

### HTML :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 newsletter-form">
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="scripts/contact.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(contactform)">
        <input type="text" name="stremail" placeholder="Your email address" ><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

### Javascript Validation :

```
function ValidateForm(Form)
{
    if (Form.stremail.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter \"Email\" ");
        Form.stremail.focus();
        return (false);
    }
    if ((/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(Form.stremail.value)) == false) {
        alert("Invalid E-mail Address! Please re-enter.");
        Form.stremail.focus();
        return (false);
    }

    return (true);
}
```

### PHP Script :

```
$stremail = $_POST["stremail"];

$to = "thebrandtgroupre@gmail.com";
$from = $stremail;
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers. = "From: \"$from\" <$from>\r\nReply-To: \"$from\" <$from>\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
$headers. = "BCC: luxuryproperties@gmail.com,pnparamasivan@gmail.com".
"\r\n"; //for testing purpose 
$subject = "The Brandt Group Newsletter Signup";
$message = "Dear Administrator,\r\n\n";
$message = $message.
"The following information was submitted to the website:<br/><br/>";

$message = $message.
"Email Address  :  ".$stremail.
"<br/><br/>";


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


header("Location: {$_SERVER["
    HTTP_REFERER "]}");
$message2 = "Thank you for newsletter signup";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for newsletter signup');</script>";
```

Any help ?

Comment: Submit the form with ajax so that you never have to leave the page. Then show the alert in the success callback.

Comment: When you say "HTML signup page" does that mean it is `*.html` or `*.php`??

Comment: are u getting error?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The form gets submitted and send the email. But I am not getting the success message.

Comment: what is the extension of form file? where your <form> exist? isnt .php file or .html file?

Comment: u have three different solutions try them.

Comment: form is .html page

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Jquery you can do like this:

**HTML side**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 newsletter-form">
    <form name="contactform" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="stremail" name="stremail" placeholder="Your email address" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

The form action and onsubmit attributs have been removed
A class has been added on stremail input

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var form = $('form ');
        form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if(ValidateForm(Form)) {
                var data = {
                    'stremail' : $('.stremail').val()
                }
                $.post("scripts/contact.php", data, function(response) {
                    if(response.success) {
                        alert(response.success);
                    }
                    else {
                        // YOUR LOGIC WHEN ERROR OCCURED
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        function ValidateForm(Form) {
            if (Form.stremail.value == "") {
                alert("Please enter \"Email\" ");
                Form.stremail.focus();
                return(false);
            }
            if ((/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(Form.stremail.value)) == false) {
                alert("Invalid E-mail Address! Please re-enter.");
                Form.stremail.focus();
                return (false);
            }
            return(true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**PHP Side**

Verify $_POST data and return response by type

```
<?php
    $response = [];

    if(isset($_POST["stremail"]) && !empty($_POST["stremail"])) {
        $stremail = $_POST["stremail"];

        $to="thebrandtgroupre@gmail.com";
        $from = $stremail;
        $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .="From: \"$from\" <$from>\r\nReply-To: \"$from\" <$from>\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
        $headers .="BCC: luxuryproperties@gmail.com,pnparamasivan@gmail.com" . "\r\n";//for testing purpose 
        $subject = "The Brandt Group Newsletter Signup";
        $message = "Dear Administrator,\r\n\n";
        $message = $message ."The following information was submitted to the website:<br/><br/>";

        $message = $message ."Email Address  :  ".$stremail."<br/><br/>";


        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        $response['success'] = "Thank you for newsletter signup";
    }
    else {
        $response['error'] = "YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE";
    }

    return $response;
?>
```

Comment: You will need to remove the redirect since you are calling this script from JS.
Remove `header("Location: {$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]}");`

Answer (score 0):

The `alert` will not happen because you have already called `header` to redirect the user. To accomplish your goal of a javascript popup I'd perhaps set a session variable after the email has been sent and then when you are redirected back to the signup page, assuming that it is a PHP enabled page, you can test for that session and perform the javascript alert.

```
<?php

    /* mail handler */
    session_start();

    $stremail = $_POST["stremail"];



    $to="thebrandtgroupre@gmail.com";
    $from = $stremail;
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"$from\" <$from>\r\nReply-To: \"$from\" <$from>\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    $headers .= "BCC: luxuryproperties@gmail.com,pnparamasivan@gmail.com\r\n"; 
    $subject = "The Brandt Group Newsletter Signup";

    $message = "
    Dear Administrator,

        The following information was submitted to the website:
        <br/><br/>
        Email Address:  {$stremail}
        <br /><br />";


    mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );


    header( "Location: {$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]}");
    $_SESSION['mail']=true;

    $message = "Thank you for newsletter signup";
?>
```

The signup page

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>signup</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 newsletter-form">
            <form name="contactform" method="post" action="scripts/contact.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this)">
                <input type="text" name="stremail" placeholder="Your email address" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php

            if( !empty( $_SESSION['mail'] ) && $_SESSION['mail']==true ){
                printf('<script>alert("%s");</script>', $message );
                unset( $_SESSION['mail'] );
            }

        ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP is not responding, as i think if for suppose if html file having .html extension, what should be happened?

Comment: file is .html extension